# Pairwise rename columns for variable even number of dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas

Example dataframe:

```
   0  1
0  1  3
1  2  4
```

Additional example dataframe:

```
   0  1  2  3
0  1  3  5  7
1  2  4  6  8
```

Expected result after pairwise renaming columns of above dataframes:

```
   Item 1 ID  Item 1 Title
0          1             3
1          2             4

   Item 1 ID  Item 1 Title  Item 2 ID  Item 2 Title
0          1             3          5             7
1          2             4          6             8
```

Renaming every dataframe column identically apart from incrementing iterator:

```
df.rename(columns={i: f'Item {i+1} ID' for i in df.columns})
```

Static dictionary mapping can't be used due to variable even number of dataframe columns.

Comment: do you want to rename based on the **value** or **position**?

Comment: @mozway Position.

Comment: is the number of columns always even?

Comment: @mozway Yes, the number of columns is always even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use a simple list comprehension:

```
df.columns = [f'Item {i+1} {x}' for i in range(len(df.columns)//2)
                                for x in ['ID', 'Title']]
```

output:

```
   Item 1 ID  Item 1 Title  Item 2 ID  Item 2 Title
0          1             3          5             7
1          2             4          6             8
```

If you need to rename in a pipeline, use:

```
def renamer(df):
    return df.set_axis([f'Item {i+1} {x}' for i in range(len(df.columns)//2)
                                          for x in ['ID', 'Title']],
                       axis=1)

df.pipe(renamer)
```